# parsing complicated json with Angular

Tags: arrays, json, angular, typescript

I want to parse an http request of this format:

```json
[
    {
        "id": 1,
        "date": "2022-01-13T00:00:00.000+00:00",
        "time": "2022-01-13T21:21:21.000+00:00",
        "office": {
            "id": 2,
            "description": "Office2",
            "phone": "123456789",
            "enabled": 1
        },
        "officeDescr": "Office2",
        "reason": 2,
        "reasonDescr": "Studies",
        "file": "1.pdf",
        "status": 0,
        "userIn": {
            "username": "name",
            "password": "'$2a$04$DR/f..s1siWJc8Xg3eJgpeB28a4V6kYpnkMPeOuq4rLQ42mJUYFGC",
            "enabled": 1,
            "firstname": "fname",
            "lastname": "lanme",
            "asm": 123,
            "office": 2,
            "authorities": [
                {
                    "authority": "ROLE_POLITIS"
                }
            ]
        },
        "commentIn": null,
        "userValid": null,
        "commentValid": null,
        "userApproved": null,
        "commentApproved": null
    },
    {
        "id": 2,
        "date": "2022-01-13T00:00:00.000+00:00",
        "time": "2022-01-13T22:22:22.000+00:00",
        "office": {
            "id": 2,
            "description": "Office2",
            "phone": "123456789",
            "enabled": 1
        },
        "officeDescr": "Office2",
        "reason": 3,
        "reasonDescr": "Health",
        "file": "2.pdf",
        "status": 0,
        "userIn": {
            "username": "somename",
            "password": "'$2a$04$DR/f..s1siWJc8Xg3eJgpeB28a4V6kYpnkMPeOuq4rLQ42mJUYFGC",
            "enabled": 1,
            "firstname": "somename",
            "lastname": "saomelastname",
            "asm": 456,
            "office": 2,
            "authorities": [
                {
                    "authority": "ROLE_POLITIS"
                }
            ]
        },
        "commentIn": null,
        "userValid": null,
        "commentValid": null,
        "userApproved": null,
        "commentApproved": null
    },
    {
        "id": 3,
        "date": "2022-01-13T00:00:00.000+00:00",
        "time": "2022-01-13T23:23:23.000+00:00",
        "office": {
            "id": 3,
            "description": "Office3",
            "phone": "777777777",
            "enabled": 1
        },
        "officeDescr": "Office3",
        "reason": 3,
        "reasonDescr": "Health",
        "file": "3.pdf",
        "status": 0,
        "userIn": {
            "username": "politis3",
            "password": "'$2a$04$DR/f..s1siWJc8Xg3eJgpeB28a4V6kYpnkMPeOuq4rLQ42mJUYFGC",
            "enabled": 1,
            "firstname": "Politis3",
            "lastname": "PolitisOffice3",
            "asm": 789,
            "office": 3,
            "authorities": [
                {
                    "authority": "ROLE_POLITIS"
                }
            ]
        },
        "commentIn": null,
        "userValid": null,
        "commentValid": null,
        "userApproved": null,
        "commentApproved": null
    }
]
```

I want get the username form the Object userIn but so far i only managed to get the whole userIn object with this:

```js
    this.applicationService.get().subscribe(
      (applications) => (console.log(applications.body.find(s=>s.userIn).userIn)));
```

Is there a way to get the attributes separately?

I tried to use brackets `[]` ant the end of `applications.body.find(s=>s.userIn).userIn` to get the attribute i want but it always returns undefined.

**EDIT**
I have this service that uses `HttpClient` to get an api from the Backend server

```js
  getPostponements(): Observable<HttpResponse<Application[]>> {
    const url = `${this.apiUrl2}/postponements`;
    return this.http.get<Application[]>(url,{ observe: 'response' })
  }
```

The `applications` type inside the `.subscribe` is  `HttpResponse<Application[]>`

I also have a Model called Application.ts:

```js
export interface Application {
    id?: number;
    date: string;
    time: string;
    reason: number;
    reasonDescr: string;
    office: number;
    officeDescr: string;
    file: string;
    userIn: number;
    commentIn: string;
    userValid: string;
    commentValid: string;
    userApproved: string;
    commentApproved: string;
    status: number;
}
```

Comment: You can get it like this: `s[0].userIn.username`

Comment: @GetOffMyLawn thank you for the reply, running this doesn't ring an angular error although the console on the browser gives me this error: `ERROR TypeError: s[0] is undefined`

Comment: try `applications.body[0].userIn.username` instead.

Comment: Thank you again, this one returns: `TS2339: Property 'username' does not exist on type 'number'` i also tried `applications.body[0].userIn[0]` which returns undefined

Comment: Did you create type definitions for this result? If so can you add them to the question.

Comment: In your interface you have `userId` defined as a `number`, it should be another interface: `userIn: { username: string; }`

Comment: You are totally right it worked i don't know how i missed that thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As @GetOffMyLawn mentioned in the comment that your model was wrong for `userIn`.

With [Json2Ts](http://json2ts.com/), the`Application` class should be as below:

```js
export interface Office {
  id: number;
  description: string;
  phone: string;
  enabled: number;
}

export interface Authority {
  authority: string;
}

export interface UserIn {
  username: string;
  password: string;
  enabled: number;
  firstname: string;
  lastname: string;
  asm: number;
  office: number;
  authorities: Authority[];
}

export interface Application {
  id: number;
  date: Date;
  time: Date;
  office: Office;
  officeDescr: string;
  reason: number;
  reasonDescr: string;
  file: string;
  status: number;
  userIn: UserIn;
  commentIn?: any;
  userValid?: any;
  commentValid?: any;
  userApproved?: any;
  commentApproved?: any;
}
```

Meanwhile, to get the `userIn`, you have to modify logic as well. *(Since you don't specify which `userIn`'s `username` you want to get, I provide some methods for your reference.)*

> Get the first `Application` item for `userIn`'s `username` (Provided by @GetOffMyLawn's comment)

```js
applications.body[0].userIn.username
```

> Get `userIn`'s `username` by `Application`'s `id`

```js
applications.body.find((x) => x.id == /* applicationId */).userIn.username
```

> Get all `userIn`s' `username`

```js
applications.body.map(
  (x: Application) => x.userIn.username
)
```

[Sample Demo on StackBlitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-udz8fj?file=src/app/application/application.component.ts)